# Initialize multiple js controls by searching DOM only once

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like a function that initializes all of my javascript/jquery controls (date pickers, sliders...).
This is mostly done using a class attribute to identify on which element to initialize the control.
Currently, I'm using a jQuery selector to get the elements.

If I understand correctly, every time I use a selector I'm searching the whole page. So if I have 10 controls and one selector for each control type, I will search the whole page 10 times.

Could there be a way to search the page only once ?

The idea would be to have a collection of css class names with the corresponding initialization method to call. Go through the page only once, and on each element if I find a corresponding class, call the initialization.

Hope I'm being clear enough.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this helps. The approach I would suggest would be to apply a class to every item that you want initialized, lets say "initializeMe" and then have specific classes for datepicker etc.

```
$(function(){
 $(".initializeMe").each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("className")){
     // lets say the class name is datepicker and you initialize datepicker here.
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Can this be adapted for controls added dynamically?  I've seen people initialize controls with on focus handlers (i.e. `$('body').on('focus', '.control-class', function() {} );`, but that would require re-factoring the above 'each' function into a named method that could be called not only from this initializer, but also from a focus handler for controls added dynamically after page initialization has already occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give each one of those elements the same class and use the .each() method?

For example:

```
    $('.canInitialize').each(function(){
        Initialize($(this));
    });
```

I don't know whether that prevents the DOM search every time or not.